# Opposite Of An Inner Join Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, outer-join

Table 1 2 columns: ID, Name

Table 2 2 columns: ID, Name

What is a query to show names from Table 1 that are not in table 2? So filtering out all the names in table 1 that are in table 2 gives the result query. Filtering is on ID not name.

Comment: Nick, all of the suggestions below (those using a join and checking for null and those that are suggest using a NOT IN clause) will work.  However, if speed is an issue, I believe that NOT IN is slower.  If speed isn't an issue, then the NOT IN is probably clearer.

Comment: The opposite of an INNER JOIN is an OUTER JOIN and it comes in two flavors: LEFT and RIGHT depending on which side of of the JOIN you want to "outer"

Comment: @Matt: your belief is wrong, `NOT IN` is faster.

Comment: You are quite right @Quassnoi.  It took me a while to get the time and a dataset large enough to measure it, but even the query execution plan shows that NOT IN is about 50% faster.  I'm not sure who told me that dirty lie in the first place!  :)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
Select * from table1
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where table2.id is null
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS is much faster. https://github.com/ebergstedt/sql_performance_left_outer_join_null_vs_not_exists

Answer (score 40):

This should perform better than the `left join...is null` version. See [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) and [here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/) for comparisons.

```
select t1.id, t1.name
    from table1 t1
    where not exists(select null from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
```

Comment: @Eduardo Cuomo: Not in SQL Server.

Answer (score 19):

Use this query

```
select
t1.*
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

this works by joining everything in t1 to whatever exists in t2.  the where clause filters out all of the records that don't exist in t2.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Name, Table2.ID 
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
WHERE Table2.ID IS NULL
```

I think that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 as t1
where t1.id not in 
  (select distinct t2.id from table2 as t2);
```